# BJT and signal source

Tags: transistors

The question maybe a bit basic, but I was not able to understand it.

When we are biasing a transistor, why don't we add the AC signal source in series with the bias voltage provider? At the output, if we use a capacitor, it should delete the magnified DC (bias voltage) part of the aggregate (AC+DC) signal. Then why do they use a coupling capacitor in series with the AC signal source instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *why don't we add the ac signal source in series with the bias voltage
> provider?*

Regarding the signals (DC and AC) then doing this: -

[image]

Is reasonably equivalent to doing this: -

[image]

So, if we can rely on Vin as having a really low DC resistance then we can use this circuit and save on C1. If Vin is a little unknown then we use a capacitor and accept that the lowest frequencies of the input signal (Vin) might not be adequately coupled to the base node without choosing a bigger capacitor.

So, we do it for practical reasons because we don't really know the DC resistance of the Vin source voltage.

Comment: thank you very much @ andy...This is what I  was looking for.

Comment: @aud098 you should look at Brian's answer too because he gives some other things to consider.

Comment: The AC source, perhaps a microphone or some very sensitive transducer, might not **like** having a large DC bias current shoved down its throat.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson that may be a slightly over-exaggerated euphemism but it may be somewhat true in some circumstances. Hence I said in my answer "Is reasonably equivalent". And it is also why I reminded the OP to look at Brian's answer.

Answer (score 6):

It can be done that way.

That is : the following circuit will work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOnRUx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(assuming there is a low impedance DC path through the AC input source V1).

However notice that R1 and R2 form a potential divider, so only 90% of the input voltage makes it as far as Q1 base, reducing the overall gain.

More seriously, R1 is a Johnson noise source in series with V1.

If you connect it to ground instead, and connect V1 to Q1 base by capacitor as normally done, the AC impedance to GND is only the source resistance of V1 which may be only a few ohms - in parallel with R1 and R2. And the Johnson noise resistance is this combined - low - resistance of a few ohms, making for a much less noisy amplifier.

(R3 is also a noise source : however a capacitor across it normally takes care of that, again by decreasing the AC resistance, while also increasing gain. R4 is also a noise source but after the input has been amplified, so it doesn't matter).

Comment: The AC source, perhaps a microphone or some very sensitive transducer, might not **like** having a large DC bias current shoved down its throat.

Comment: Maybe the AC signal source already has a series output capacitor. Then the transistor would be saturated with it disconnecting the current in R2.

Answer (score 2):

The AC source, perhaps a microphone or some very sensitive transducer, might not **like** having a large DC bias current shoved down its throat.

Answer (score 1):

Typically we assume that the AC source is injected at the base along with the DC bias because that fits best with typical amplifier usage: usually you're either plugging a source into the thing (microphone, tape head, some sensor, etc.), or you're cascading amplifiers and that's the easiest way to implement the cascade.

There's certainly other possible arrangements.  E.g. if you're designing a radio and you want it to be transformer-coupled, **and** you have split supplies, you could do this rather contrived amplifier:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fexmTx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that I'm not *advocating* that this be done (although I've seen similar circuit notions).  I'm just saying that it *could* be done.